# variables XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have this:

```
var fechastotales = [];
fechastotales.push(fecha1);
fechastotales.push(fecha2);
fechastotales.push(fecha3);
fechastotales.push(fecha4);
var ajax_url = "buscarpeli.php";
var params = "peli=1768&fechastotales=" + fechastotales;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    var ajax_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    var ajax_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
ajax_request.open("POST", ajax_url, true);
ajax_request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
ajax_request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
ajax_request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
ajax_request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (ajax_request.readyState == 4) {
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(ajax_request.responseText);
        alert("jsonObj.answer: " + jsonObj.answer);
    }
}
ajax_request.send(params);
```

fechastotales doesnt pass correctly.
any idea??
thanks u!

Comment: `fechastotales` is an array, you can't add an array to a string and send it?

Comment: thanks but sorry how can i do that?

Comment: you need to url encode it. `encodeURIComponent(myArray)`. this will cause the array to be passed as a comma seperated list.

Comment: hey thanks.. the ajax_url is [code]$fechastotales=$_POST['fechastotales'];
foreach ($fechastotales as $number){
$data['news']=compr($numer,$_POST['peli']);
if($data['news']=="yes"){break;}
}echo json_encode($data);[/code]
if i use encodeURIComponent. how can ajax_url receive the variables?